# After RealVNC installation, the dock has changed (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, vnc, ubuntu-dock

Before RealVNC (5.0.7) installation, the dock was simply permanently there, docked on the left hand side of the screen.

After RealVNC installation, the dock can only be seen when clicking on "Activities" and it is the older style, rounded at the edges, with a red line under the active applications instead of a dot like in the newer style.

Why did the dock format (or perhaps the whole desktop environment) swap back to this and how can I revert it?

Already tested/further info; The dock is not set to auto-hide. The tool `gnome-tweaks` cannot fix it. RealVNC does not seem to have a related setting for it. It could be related to something else (i.e. that RealVNC is not the cause of the issue). The issue happens both when connected remotely as well as with a screen attached directly to the server.

```
$ apt policy gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:
  Installed: 0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3
  Candidate: 0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3
  Version table:
 *** 0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.9.1 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages

$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions
@as []
```

Comment: Looks like you have no extensions enabled, including the Ubuntu Dock extension. What did you try to do with `gnome-tweaks`? Can you enable the Ubuntu Dock extension from the 'Extensions' section of Tweaks app?

Comment: Hum. I am starting to think that this is resolution related. Just rebooting with a high-res screen (1920x1080) has brought the dock bar back on the left hand side as normal. Previously it has a 1024 x 768 screen connected, so I wonder if Ubuntu just removes the dock from the main screen to save real estate with such lower resolution screens.